# Dynamically Modify ActionMenuBar Items When Category is Clicked

Tags: delphi

I am creating a menu using an ActionManager and an ActionMenuBar. I want to add and subtract items from the menu when the top-level menu node is clicked but I can't find a clean way to do this. For example, I want to create a top-level menu "Windows" that hosts items corresponding to every modeless form. I can create the top-level "Windows" menu by creating a Category named Windows in the ActionManager and dragging "Windows" to the menu bar. When "Windows" is clicked I would then like to populate Items property with TActionClientItems corresponding to the application's modeless forms. I do know the mechanics of dynamically adding action clients at runtime (for example, in the form's oncreate event) but I can't find an action that fires when a Category (in this case, "Windows") is clicked.

I could work around this by updating the menu whenever a form is hidden or shown, but this seems inelegant compared to updating the menu on demand. I tried attaching an action to the "Windows" actionclientitem but the action's onexecute doesn't fire (apparently because it is a Category).

The failure of the onexecute handler to be called can be demonstrated with the following steps:

1. In Actionmanager create action named "Action1" and assigned its
   category property to "Windows".
2. Drag the "Windows" category to
   the menubar.
3. Create an action named WindowAction and assigned no
   category to it.
4. Add "Showmessage('x');" to the OnExecute of
   WindowAction.
5. In designer click on ActionManager1->ActionBars->0->Items-."0-Windows" (which is TActionClients[0]). Set TActionClients[0].Action := WindowAction.
6. Correct the caption of TActionClients[0] so that it is again "Windows".
7. Run program, click "Windows" on menu and showmessage not shown.

Comment: Click 'Windows' menu item/category in the designer, assign an action, change the caption of the action to 'Windows' and attach an OnExecute handler.

Comment: I have tried exactly that and the Onexecute handler is never fired. Sertac Akyuz have you actually tested your suggestion?

Comment: Somehow existing category items have been lost in my first test. Can't get it to work again now. Not reliable...